# How to hide/show columns in a ListView control?

Tags: winapi

In Windows Explorer, you can hide/show columns. Is this feature also supported by the Windows `ListView` control? (I am assuming that Windows Explorer uses another control that we don't have access to).

Comment: [About Header Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775238.aspx): *"List-view controls already have header controls. Instead of creating a header control for a list-view control, you use [LVM_GETHEADER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774937.aspx) or [ListView_GetHeader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761290.aspx) to retrieve the existing control."*

Comment: You don't need to go that far. A ListView bas its own messages for manipulating columns. `LVM_DELETECOLUMN`, `LVM_INSERTCOLUMN`, and `LVM_SETCOLUMN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ListView_GetColumn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761252(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`ListView_SetColumn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775070.aspx) to get/set a column's attributes as needed.  To hide a column, get its current width and then set its width to 0.  To show a column, restore its previous width.

However, when a column is "hidden", the user can still grab the divider on the  column's edge and resize the column manually.  To avoid that, you can either:

1. completely remove the column using [`ListView_DeleteColumn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761236.aspx), and then use [`ListView_InsertColumn()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775032.aspx) when you want to re-show it.
2. subclass the ListView to intercept [`HDN_BEGINTRACK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775263.aspx) notifications from the ListView's header control, returning `TRUE` for "hidden" columns to prevent them from resizing.